# Printing menu hierarchy

Tags: java, hierarchy

I am given a collection of strings (paths to menu items) that look like this

```
/home
/about
/about/staff
/about/staff/sector1
/about/staff/sector2
/products
/products/section1
```

and I need to print them in a way where the hierarchy of the menu will be shown like this:

```
.home
.about
....staff
.......sector1
.......sector2
.products
....section1
```

This is my code:

```
void printItem(int indent, String path)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<indent; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        String [] items = null;
        if(path.contains("/"))
        {
            items = path.split("/");

            for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(items[i]);
                printItem(indent+3, items[i]);

            }
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

The problem with my code is that I don't know how to stop it from printing the same parent more times. For example, let's say I have these 3 paths:

```
/about
/about/staff
/about/staff/sector1
```

I end up getting this output:

```
..about
....staff
.....about
....staff
....sector1
....
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of this issue?